# Centos 7 Remote SSH access denied

Tags: ssh, centos, centos7

I installed Centos7, all fine, till I want to access via SSH, I get always Access Denied.

1. I get it with the root user, and another new created user
2. I tested SSH within the LAN, so no firewall issue
3. For the root user "PermitRootLogin yes" is set.
4. SSH service is started

... till now, I have no clue what I ignored to set it right to have it working.

I got a look into the secure log. When I try to login with the root user on the LAN, I do like:

```
ssh root@192.168.2.11
```

in log I get: invalid user root@localhost from 192.168.2.108

When I try through VPN-tunnel:

```
ssh root@192.168.2.11
```

in log I get: invalid user kristoxxxxxxxx

this is my username on my OSX device. why is this one passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be due to RSA or DSA keys, os please delete or backup following files from /etc/ssh director to another one.

`ssh_host_dsa_key,  ssh_host_dsa_key.pub,  ssh_host_key,  ssh_host_key.pub,  ssh_host_rsa_key , ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` etc

Now restart your `sshd` service

```
service sshd restart
```